# Having issues uploading an image via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Sorry if the title isn't descriptive enough!

The idea is to have a div popup and allow users to type in their feedback and possibly submit a screenshot.

This is the javascript inside the page (which is called via ajax into a div).

### Javascript

```
$("#submitFeedback").click(function(){
  //Check if the form is valid
  if($("#form").valid()){
    $("#form").hide(); //Hide the form
    $("#feedbackReport").append("<h2 style='color:white'>Submitting!</h2><hr />" +
      "<div style='text-align: center'><img src='images/loader.gif' /></div>");//Display loading spinner
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "ajax/submit_feedback.php",
      cache: false,
      data: $("#form").serialize(),//serialize form for submission
      success: function(data) {
        $("#feedbackReport").empty();//Clear form after submission
        $("#feedbackReport").append("<h2>Thank you!</h2><span id='close'>&#10006;</span><hr />"
          +"Your feedback has been submitted successfully!"
          +"<br /><br /><span id='cancel'>Close</span>");
        $("#cancel,#close").click(function(){
          $("#feedbackReport").parent().hide();
        });
      }
    });
    return false;//Prevent page from changing
  }
});
```

Now, if point my browser to the actual ajax page (ajax/feedback.php) and submit an image, it works fine! When I run it from index.php and call the feedback window via ajax, it wont submit my picture, only the text.

I know my submit_feedback.php page works fine because of this, I just have no idea why it won't post the image properly.

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax can't do file uploads. You have to use something different such as https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Comment: That would explain a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Actually you can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) to upload files via ajax, if your browser supports it

Comment: @Musa Agreed, just didn't think it was compatible with enough browsers to be worth mentioning. Guess I was wrong http://caniuse.com/xhr2

Comment: You most certainly can upload files via Ajax, and you don't have to use FormData.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I am currently using FormData and it's working, but I do like knowing my alternatives :).

Comment: @RayNicholus I would also like you to elaborate on this uploading via ajax. Please share your solution.

Comment: @JuanGonzales This has been covered dozens of times on SO alone.  Have a look via the search box.

Answer (score -1):

Ajax does not allow file uploads however the neat trick  is to use an iframe that holds the file upload form and auto submit it when a file is selected.

This way only the iframe is redirected and it gives it an ajax feel.

[Read more here](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/ajax-file-uploads-with-the-iframe-method/)

Comment: You can upload files via Ajax in all browsers that support the File API.